# Наклонный блок с текстом на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Мне нужно поместить текст в такой блок, чтоб располагался под наклоном. Нагуглил что это можно сделать только через js, кто может подсказать как именно? Какими методами и свойствами, где искать? Если кто то знает как без js обойтись, смело можете подсказывать. Принимаю любую информацию по теме, не стесняйтесь. Всем Спасибо!

[image]

Comment: через `css` можно сделать это, с помощью `transform` и `rotate`.

Comment: А можете дасть ссылку, у кого так получилось ? Текст должен выравниваться по блоку, каждая последующая строчка имеет больше отступ слева, меньше справа

Answer (score 2):

Через скрипт:

```js
$(function() {
  indent($("div")[0]);
});

function indent(div) {
  if (document.createRange) {
    var rng = document.createRange();
    rng.selectNodeContents(div);
    var len = rng.toString().length;
    var start = rng.toString().search(/.\s/);
    if (start < 0) return;
    var txt = div.childNodes[0];
    rng.setEnd(txt, start);
    var startRect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rect;
    for (var i = start + 1; i < len; i++) {
      rng.setEnd(txt, i);
      rect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (rect.bottom > startRect.bottom) {
        rng.setStart(txt, i - 1);
        rng.setEnd(txt, len);
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "indent";
        rng.surroundContents(div);
        indent(div);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
    rng.moveToElementText(div);
    var x = rng.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    rng.collapse();
    var rect = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y = rect.bottom;
    rng.moveToPoint(x - 1, y - 1);
    rng.moveEnd("textedit");
    var html = "<div class=\"indent\">" + rng.text + "</div>";
    rng.pasteHTML(html);
    div = $(".indent", div)[0];
    rng.moveToElementText(div);
    var pos = rng.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (pos.bottom > rect.bottom) {
      indent(div);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.wapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.indent {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

P.S. Оригинал тут http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/CmguZ/7/

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать через css полигонами. Вот удобный и легкий инструмент. [Вот удобный и легкий инструмент.](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: тоесть расположить 2 техугольника по краям и текст выровнять? В продакшэне уже используют? Поддержка кажется еще маленькая?

Comment: Зачем два треугольника?  Посмотри в инструменте с права есть выбор фигур. Я их использовал еще в 2014 году. Если тебе прям нужна поддержка старых браузеров ищи решение с JS. Вот только с текстом конечно проблемно будет.

Comment: фигуру или картинку можно сделать, но если поместить текст внутри такого необычного блока, то он не будет заполнять блок, а будет выходить за рамки. Нужно чтобы текст распределился внутри блока повторяя его форму

Answer (score 1):

Для этого не нужен `javascript`. Можно на `css transform`.

```css
div{
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Все круто, только мне нужно чтобы текст не деформировался, но располагался в таком положении, в этом как бы вся сложность

Comment: @max, вы можете дать тексту отрицательный rotate

Comment: @St1myL, каким же образом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот что имел ввиду - https://codepen.io/St1myL/pen/ypWzEN

Comment: @St1myL, так не годится - размеры области возвращаются: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVcvK.png

Comment: @max,  
`нужно чтобы текст не деформировался, но располагался в таком положении` - так не получится сделать, такой-же наклон тексту, без трансформации, не реально, просто сделать наклоненный блок, а внутри текст, да. А иначе, у вас, текст будет трансформироваться под положение блока.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это я не учёл, благодарю за поправку

Comment: @St1myL, можно попробовать каждую букву обернуть в `span` и его поворачивать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати, я так и не понял, как вы сделали так, чтобы буквы вылезли за границы блока?

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил больше текста, повернул и все равно не выходит

Comment: @St1myL, просто текст из чередования буквы "a" и пробела.

Answer (score 0):

если на css то только так получилось (но жаль вопрос о javascript):

```css
*{
  marin:0;
}
.div{
  width:70%;
  text-align:justify;
}
span.float{
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
<span class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:10px;"></span>
<span class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:30px;"></span>
<span  class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:50px;"></span>
<span  class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:70px;"></span>
<span  class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:90px;"></span> 
<span  class="float" style="display:inline-block; width:110px;"></span> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eum excepturi cum accusantium. Beatae cumque cum quasi commodi nisi sunt, voluptatibus nemo, corporis optio praesentium magnam dolorum vel consectetur provident, dolor unde molestiae repellendus eum? Quas illum reprehenderit repellat voluptatem? Est dolorem velit sapiente recusandae temporibus laborum natus ipsam tempora?
</div>
```